# Global variable from included file in static function

Tags: php, global

I have *index.php* with included file *strings.php* for translating phrases. In *strings.php* is included file based on user language: *$lang.php*. This *$lang.php* file is automatically generated from *$lang.ini* and contains single array:

```
  <?php $translation = array (
      'USER_PROFILE' => 'Uživatelský profil',
      'MESSAGES' => 'Zprávy',
      'NOTIFICATIONS' => 'Oznámení',
      'SETTINGS' => 'Nastavení',
      ...
```

There is a class Strings with static function and globally assigned array *$translation* from *$lang.php* in *strings.php*:

```
include_once('cache/'.$lang.'.php');

class Strings {
    static public function translate($string) {
        global $translation;
        ...
    }
}
```

But *$translation* in *translate()* function returns null in this case. If I include *$lang.php* in *index.php* it suddenly works, but if I call *Strings::translate()* function in other file, *$translation* again returns null. I don't understand this behavior. (Sorry for english)

Comment: It depends **if** and **where** you include `$lang.php`. Be sure you include it on the global context (not in a function) and before calling `translate()`.

Comment: I include it before (outside) _class Strings_ in same file. And this class is autoloaded when necessary, so I guess it include _$lang.php_ file as well. Or not?

Comment: Then make sure the file `$lang.php` is really included. Put an `echo($lang);` before the inclusion (to check if variable `$lang` is visible at that point and contains what you expect) and a `print_r($translation);` after the inclusion (to check that the file was actually included). Turn the error reporting on (`error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`) before anything else in `index.php` or use `require` instead of `include` to be sure the code finds the file (assuming `$lang` is correct). Or just put an `echo()` in the language file and check if the message appears in the output.

Comment: I have always error reporting on. When `var_dump($translation)` after include `$lang.php` it correctly shows this array, but it is not included if I call `Strings::translate()` elsewhere. I think it somehow relates with autoloading of Strings class.

Comment: Right now I created private functions in Strings class. First one define `$lang` variable and second one include `$lang.php` and returns `$translation` array. In `translate()` function I call this second one function instead of defining global and now it works.

Comment: Hmm, do you call `Strings::translate()` from a function when it fails?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72317/discussion-between-axiac-and-hovado).

Comment: Yes, I call it from many other classes and theirs functions.

Comment: If you call `Strings::translate()` from a function and `strings.php` is not included yet, the autoloader will find and include it. `strings.php` includes `$lang.php` that creates the variable `$translation` inside the function's scope and not in the global scope. This is why `Strings::translate()` cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the way the file `$lang.php` is included, the variable `$translation` lands as a local variable in a function and not as a `global` variable as method `Strings::translate()` expects it.

After we discussed in chat and I understood the problem, I can suggest two solutions:

#### Solution 1 (the quick workaround)

Change file `$lang.php`:

```
<?php global $translation = array (
    'USER_PROFILE' => 'Uživatelský profil',
    ...
```

This way the variable `$translation` is created in the global context and everything works as expected.

#### Solution 2 (a better design)

Limit the scope of the variable `$translation`.

File `$lang.php`:

```
<?php return array (
    'USER_PROFILE' => 'Uživatelský profil',
    ...
```

This way no variable is create (neither local nor global) and this removes the source of confusion.

File `strings.php`:

```
class Strings {

    static $translation;

    static private function initialize() {
         global $lang;
         static::$translation = include_once('cache/'.$lang.'.php');
    }

    static public function translate($string) {
        if (! isset(static::$translation)) {
            static::initialize();
        }

        // use static::$translation instead of global $translation
    }
}
```

#### Solution 3 (the correct design)

An even better design (the correct one, in fact) is to make method `initialize()` public, change `$lang` as its parameter and call it from your code as soon as you determined the value of `$lang`.

File `strings.php`:

```
class Strings {

    static $translation;

    // Call this method once, as soon as you determined what
    // language you need to use
    static public function initialize($lang) {
         static::$translation = include_once('cache/'.$lang.'.php');
    }

    static public function translate($string) {
        // use static::$translation instead of global $translation
    }
}
```

Comment: I just find out that method `return array(...);` in included `$lang.php` doesn't work and it should be `$translation = array(...); return $translation;`.